# How switch Mono<A>.empty() to another type item Mono<B>

Tags: kotlin, project-reactor

Follow the kotlin code bellow, I need to use a `EMPTY_A` to swith `Mono<A>.empty` to another `Mono<B>` instance, I think this way is ugly:

```
// if getA(id) is empty then getB(id) and convert it to A
fun get(id: Int): Mono<A> {
  return getA(id)
    .switchIfEmpty(Mono.just(EMPTY_A))
    .flatMap { if (it == EMPTY_A) getB(id).map { convertB2A(it) } else Mono.just(it) }
}

// business methods
fun getA(id: Int): Mono<A> {...}
fun getB(id: Int): Mono<B> {...}
fun convertB2A(b: B): A {...}

val EMPTY_A: A = A(0)
data class A(val id: Int)
data class B(val id: Int)
```

Simplify, I want to use code template like these:

```
fun get(id: Int): Mono<A> {
  return getA(id)
    .switchIfEmpty(getB(id))
    .map { convertB2A(it) }
}
```

But failed to compile actually, because method [switchIfEmpty](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/blob/v3.1.6.RELEASE/reactor-core/src/main/java/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.java#L3203) can only switch to another item with the original type.
Any idea?

Comment: Try `transform()` instead of `switchIfEmpty()`

Answer (score 1):

Follow @ArtemBilan advice, after some test, I found the solution:

```
fun get(id: Int): Mono<A> {
  return getA(id) 
    .transform {
      if (it == Mono.empty<A>()) getB(id).map { convertB2A(it) }
      else it 
    }
}
```